# Best practice for drop shadow and gradient on website navbar

Tags: gradient, drop-shadow

I'm using a medium blue color for a large navbar at the top of a website home page. The logo and nav links are white/very light blue. I don't know if the navbar blue should be solid or have a gradient, and I don't know if it should have a drop shadow on the bottom (below the navbar is white color background).

Are there any best practices for navbar effects?

Comment: Not sure there are "best practices" for this. It ultimately all boils down to the design you (or the client) want(s). I'd be interested if there were some defines guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to consult your client on the matter as this is a situational manner. Though, if you are looking to try something out I would recommend a very subtle drop shadow under the navbar to help distinguish it. Though the color alone would do it and it seems lately that flat design is becoming a bigger trend.

Also, I would advise against the gradient in the navbar. The navbar is one of the, if not the most important element on a website. You do not want to make it hard to read or anything in that manner. The only exception to this is if your navbar is needed to look like it has volume. Still, it would need to be subtle. So all in all, best practices would be to consult your client on the situation, take in their opinion, use the best course of action and go with it.

Also it doesn't hurt to try different variations of this layout and look to give your client options.